# VBA setting text.box in user form equal to a cell or certain value from data base

Tags: vba, userform

I am trying to create a user-form that will automatically create x amount of printed out user forums from a data base. I cant figure out how to get the certain value from the data base to be inputted into the certain text.box on my user-form. Right now the code will go through my data base and find all bridges that are "slabs" and then find the corresponding NBI number, but I can't figure out the exact syntax to use it seems like. I have tried using various different methods, but all seem to have some sort of problem. final goal is to fill out a user-form with the text boxes `NBI NO.(textbox(1))`, `Local ID No.(textbox(5))`, `structure No(textbox(4))`, and `type(textbox(3))`.

```
Sub word()
Dim i As Integer
Dim feat As String

feat = ("Slab")

Range("O4:O13").Clear

For i = 2 To 23089
If Cells(i, 11) = feat Then
    TextBox(1).Text = Cells(i, 11)

Else
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do, if there are 10 slabs add 10 text boxes and populate with the contents?

Comment: No, I want the code to "find" a bridge that is a slab, and then fill out the rest of the user form with its corresponding NBI number, and other information. right now the code goes through the data table until it finds a bridge that's a "slab", when it finds that certain row i then need to set that text-box equal to (or have that cells value fill out the text box) a different cell that's on the same row, just different column.

Comment: the line of code "TextBox(1).Text = Cells(i, 11)" is incorrect, I need some other type of syntax or logical way of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've indicated in your question and comments, this should fix your issue:

**NOTE:** *The below code is referencing data on 'Sheet1' using a UserForm named 'UserForm1' and a TextBox on that UserForm named 'TextBox1'.*

```
Sub text()

Dim i As Integer
Dim feat As String

feat = ("Slab")

Range("O4:O13").Clear

For i = 2 To 23089
If Cells(i, 11) = feat Then
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Text

Else
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The change I've made is in the `If...Else` statement, I've made reference to the UserForm with `UserForm1`. Rather than referencing the index of the TextBox, I've referenced it by name `TextBox1` and lastly, I've specified the Sheet and what data from the cell I want `Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Text`.

By doing this the code will loop through each row of the sheet between 2 and 23089 checking column 'K' for "Slab". If it's found it will populate `TextBox1` with "Slab".

**NOTE:**

1. If you are running this code in your UserForm module you should replace the `UserForm1.` reference with `Me.`.
2. If you want the TextBox to populate the text from another cell in the Row (as you said in your question), change the column index in the line `UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Text` from 11 to whatever the correct column index is.
3. Be sure to change the above code to use the correct object names (`UserForm1` should be your userforms name, `TextBox1` should the the relevant TextBox name etc.) Also don't forget to change the `Sheets(1).` reference to reference the correct sheet for your workbook.

I'll leave it to you to adjust the code to reference your values correctly.